# Big negative integer representation in a LinkedList

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list

My LinkedList represents big numbers by having one digit in each of the nodes.

I can represent positive big integers in a LinkedList with this code:

```
public BigInteger(int x) 
{
    list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    while (x > 0) 
    {
        list.push(( x % 10 ));
        x = x / 10;
    }
}
```

Declaring:

```
BigInteger bigPositive = new BigInteger(91234)
```

Produces:

```
 [9,1,2,3,4]
```

However, I am not sure how to represent big negative integers such as -9321312345

Comment: is BigInteger here your own class? There is already a biginteger implementation.

Comment: This will be more complicated (to make) and a lot slower than `java.math.BigInteger`, could be an interesting project though if you're doing it for fun

Comment: This seems incredibly inefficient.  You're storing one list node plus one BigInteger for every digit. Then there's the issue of storing it in decimal, which will make arithmetic "interesting".  Is this just for your education or do you intend to use this in "production" code somewhere? BTW, just add a `boolean` sign (true=negative, false=positive) member to your class.

Comment: This is just for my own education. I am trying to learn how to implement my own LinkedList, this was just one of the problems I ran into. Eventually, I want to make methods that can perform simple arithmetic operations on the LinkedList, so I want to know how to handle the negative numbers.

Comment: Store the sign as an extra `int` field such as -1, 0 or +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public BigInteger(int x)` this value for `int x` the input itself would be the limit so you can never go over.

Why not just have ?

```
public BigInteger(int x){
   bigIntValue = x;
}
```

Because that's not the point. You want to be able to create values bigger then the intended `int` from the input.

The better option IMO would be something along the lines of add a `String` as the input then having an operation that can push `int's` or something you want into the back or front of the `linklist`.

```
public BigInteger(String x) 
{   
    int endLoop = 0;
    list = new LinkedList<char>();
    // have a boolean for negative in your class then multiple by 
    // negative one to your operations if its true.
    if(x.charAt(0) == '-'){
        this.negative = true;
        endLoop = 1;
    }
    list = new LinkedList<char>();
    int i = x.length() - 1;
    while(i >= endLoop) {
        if(!validNumber(x.charAt(i)) //fail 

        list.push(( x.charAt(i)));
        i--;
    }

}

// this checks if it's a number.
boolean validNumber(char n){
    for(int i = 48; i =< 57; i++){
        if(n = i) return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

You can even change the type of your lists to int if you want by writing a converter from char to int.

Answer (score 1):

You could push a 1 or a 0 to the front of the list, indicating whether it was positive or negative.  For instance:

- (15) would map to [1 1 5]
- (-13) would map to [0 1 3]
- (1) would map to [1 1]

And so on.  You'd just have to know to interpret that first number as a sign (+/-), and not part of the value.

Answer (score 1):

If BigInteger is your own custom class, you could add a Boolean property that determines whether the integer is positive or negative.

Then, in your constructor, you could determine the sign of the integer and set that property accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same they do in binary; by having the firstmost digit determine the sign

```
0b0100 ==  4
0b1100 == -4
```

Similarly you could write

```
{0, 1, 1} ==  11 
{1, 1, 1} == -11,
```

Although this deviates from the initial idea; since you ARE working with integers, you could do this:

```
{-1, 1} == -11 
{ 1, 1} ==  11
```